# regex - match exact text within square brackets

Tags: regex

I want to convert `"categories": ["Doctors", "Health & Medical"],`

to `"categories": ["Doctors, Health & Medical"],`

In otherwords, I want to find `" ,"` (with space in the middle of open qoute and  comma).

then replace with `,`

However, `" ,"` repeats elsewhere in the document therefore using `" ,"` alone won't be enough. The best best is to say find `" ,"` within `[...]`

For example: "categories": ["Doctors", "Health & Medical"], "city": "Phoenix", "count": 9

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am just using text editor to reformat the strings so that i can import it in my other Java programs. I can find everything inside `[..]` with this `\[".*"]` but it is not enough to narrow down to `" ,"`

Comment: Don't treat JSON as string. Parse it, transform the structure where needed, then restringify if needed. Regex is a bad choice here.

Comment: @Amadan, agree. But im learning regex and find this problem interesting. Thank you for the advice

Comment: @user5705407 what regex engine are you using? All of them support different capabilities

Comment: Just saying, part of learning a tool is also learning when not to use it...

Comment: "with space in the middle of open qoute and comma". Your example `"categories": ["Doctors", "Health & Medical"],` doesn't seem to represent that! The space is in between the comma and the closing quote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you *should* avoid regex if you can.

It is pretty trivial to achieve something like this in JavaScript with a single line.

For instance, you could just use the `.join()` method:

```
obj.categories = [obj.categories.join(', ')];
```

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/9a0ue0qs/)

---

However, if you don't have a choice, you can use the following:

```
/((?:\[[^\]]*?)|(?:(?<!^)\G[^\]]*?))(?:", ")(?=[^\]]*"\])/g
```

Then replace the matches with `\1,`.

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/vV1aM7/1)

Based on your test cases, the string:

```
"categories": ["Doctors", "Health", "Other"], "city": "Phoenix", "count": 9
```

would output:

```
"categories": ["Doctors, Health, Other"], "city": "Phoenix", "count": 9
```